# Is possible to use the object instead of Switch statement?

Tags: javascript, json, object, switch-statement, javascript-objects

I use the switch statement in my code often, I read about the object and a lot of developers say that is better to use. I want to use less code, do you guys know an alternative way of making this code more efficient?

full code link here - https://jsfiddle.net/lmanhaes/5ebjypo1/

I shared two examples below that I would like to change.

Many thanks.

```js
//fisrt example
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#country").change(function () {
        var cityName;
        var select = $("#country option:selected").val(); 
        switch (select) {
            case "England":
                cityName = "england";
                city(cityName);
                break;
            case "Scotland":
                cityName = "scotland";
                city(cityName);
                break;
            case "Wales":
                cityName = "wales";
                city(cityName);
                break;
            case "Northern Ireland":
                cityName = "nireland";
                city(cityName);
                break;
            default:
                $("#city").empty();

                break;
        }
    });

    $("#city").change(function () { 
        var cityValue = $("#city").val();
        getWeatherApi(cityValue);
    });
    
 //second example
    
    $.each(response.weather, function (index, value) {  
                    cond = response.weather[index].main;

                    

                    switch (cond) { 
                        case "Clouds":
                            icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/cloud.png" alt="cloud" width="70px" height="80%"/>';
                            break;
                        case "Hail":
                            icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/hail.png" alt="hail" width="70px" height="80%"/>';
                            break;
                        case "Heavy Cloud":
                            icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/heavy cloud.png" alt="heavy-clouds" width="70px" height="80%"/>';
                            break;
                        case "Heavy Rain":
                            icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/heavy rain.png" alt="heavy-rain" width="70px" height="80%"/>';
                            break;
                        case "Rain":
                            icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/rain.png" alt="rain" width="70px" height="80%"/>';
                            break;
                        case "Sleet":
                            icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/sleet.png" alt="sleet" 70px" height="80%"/>';
                            break;
                        case "Snow":
                            icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/snow.png" alt="snow" width="70px" height="80%"/>';
                            break;
                        case "Sun":
                            icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/sun.png" alt="sun" 70px" height="80%"/>';
                            break;
                        case "Sun and Clouds":
                            icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/sun and cloud.png" alt="sun-cloud" width="70px" height="80%"/>';
                            break
                        case "Thunderstorm":
                            icon = '<img src="./weather_icons/thunderstorm.png" alt="thunderstorm" width="70px" height="80%"/>';
                            break;
                        default: 
                            icon = '';
                            break;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: you mean something like `const obj = { a: "apple", b: "banana"}; let  key = 'a'; let value = obj[key];` will result in value being apple?

Comment: In addition to other posted advice, A fair chunk of your complexity is accommodating essentially the same values.  I would recommend simplifying this a bit more. There's no need to build in extra structure to accommodate a lowercase vs. proper cased version of the value. Just use the lowercased value in the structure/mapping and `"foo bar".replace(/\b\w/g,function(m){return m.toUpperCase();})` to proper case it for the UX

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var cityName;
var select = $("#country option:selected").val(); 
var countryToCity = {
    "England": "england",
    "Scotland": "scotland",
    "Wales": "wales",
    "": ""
}
if (select in countryToCity) {
    city(countryToCity[select]);
}
$("#city").empty();
```

Not sure it's more readable, but you can use this syntax.

The object has keys and values. Each key has it's own value, so in the above example - the value of "England" is "england" - so you can find the value based on the key.

You can do exactly the same with the images that you have.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are in the right direction, when your switch statement code seem to be too big, maybe would be better use an object instead, so you should consider the following

```
const getCity = (cityName) => () => city(cityName);
const cityAction = {
England: getCity('england'),
Scotland: getCity('scotland'),
Wales: getCity('wales'),
'Northern Ireland': getCity('nireland'),
_UNKNOWN_: () => $("#city").empty()
}

// then use it like so:

 $("#city").change(function () { 
    var cityValue = $("#city").val();
    const cityHandler = cityAction[cityValue] || cityAction._UNKNOWN_;
    cityHandler();
 });
```

Hope it can help you.

> You can replicate this for the switch image too, as you can see your  tag has the same pattern, just the image name and its alt attribute changes, so it can be moved to an single function to do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are too main differences betwenn an object and a switch-case block. 
An object is a data-structure to safe data and a switch block is a syntactic sturcture to shorten an if-else-structure. For memory and cpu performance use a switch-case statement.

For better code overview:
Look in your case blocks for dublicates. You can also outsource your switch statements in own functions. For more overview use clean function-names and outsource such function to modules.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#country").change(function () {
        var cityName;
        var select = $("#country option:selected").val(); 
        var convertedCityName = convertCityNames(select);
        if(convertedCityName) {
            city(convertCityNames);
        } else {
            $("#city").empty();
        }
    });

    function convertCityNames(inputedCityName) {
        switch (inputedCityName) {
            case "England":
                return "england";
            case "Scotland":
                return "scotland";
            case "Wales":
                return "wales";
            case "Northern Ireland":
                return "nireland";
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
```